# How to use jquery selector having element type and ID

Tags: jquery

I'm using this selector
 `$("textarea #myTextArea").val(text);` and it's not working. If I remove the ID and use the class it's working. Why isn't jquery able to find the element here?

Comment: fyi, just the id is optimized in jquery - you will be slowing down the selector considerably

Comment: Daniel is right, you should use only $("myTextArea") instead of your selector. It directly uses javascript's getElementById() so it's fast and efficient. When using your selector, the script will select all elements (in this case textareas) and iterate through them until it finds the proper one.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot do that as the same ID is used else where, in the same page, I know that's terrible, but I have to live with that.

Comment: Why do you have to live with that? That's not valid HTML. Perhaps you are using IDs where classes may be more appropriate?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Because of the space. With the space it says the `#myTextArea` within a `textarea`.

```
$("textarea#myTextArea").val(text);
```

Comment: "textarea" is not just redundant. It is about 80% slower. Here, I created a test: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performance-test123

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the space:

```
$("textarea#myTextArea").val(text);
```

At the moment you're trying to select an element with ID `myTextArea` that is a descendant element of a `textarea`

As Jared Farrish mentions in the comments removing the element type would be more efficient:

```
$("#myTextArea").val(text);
```

If your document is valid then every ID will only used be once so this is still correct.

Comment: Or remove `textarea` altogether.

Comment: To clarify for @Manoj, when you use a space it will try to select elements with the ID myTextArea that are *descendants* of your textarea.