# Get the input type by passing its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to pass an input ID and get its corresponding type.

Eg.

```
<input id = "1" type = "date"/>
<input id = "2" type = "text"/>
```

So passing "1" would return **date** and passing "2" would return **text**.

I have looked at a few examples but none that work for my case:

[How to use jquery selector having element type and ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609345/how-to-use-jquery-selector-having-element-type-and-id)

[finding the type of an element using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608410/finding-the-type-of-an-element-using-jquery)

What I have so far:

```
$("#my_select").on('click',function(){
        var fieldID = document.querySelector('.selected').id
        console.log("id is " + fieldID);
        var elementType = $(this).prev().prop('.selected');
        console.log("element type " + elementType)
});
```

Comment: are the ids unique in whole document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var type = $("#id").attr("type");
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

```
$("#my_select").on('click',function(){
            var fieldID = document.querySelector('.selected').id
                console.log("id is " + fieldID);
            var elementType = $('#' + fieldID).prop('type');
            console.log("element type " + elementType)

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution.

```js
$("#my_select").on('change', function() {
  var fieldID = document.getElementById($(this).val());
  console.log(`id is ${fieldID.id} and type is ${fieldID.type}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="1" type="date" />
<input id="2" type="text" />
<select id='my_select'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/bpq58x8m/

```js
getType = function(id){
 console.log($('#' + id).attr('type'));
}

$('input').click(function(){
 getType($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = "1" type = "date"/>
<input id = "2" type = "text"/>
```

**Click** on the **input** will give you back the **type**. 
I added an extra function just for your reference, you can ignore that and combine two into a single.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#my_select").on('click',function(){
    var fields=$("#your-Form-Id").children();
    for(i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
        var type = field[i].type ||  field[i].tagName.toLowerCase();
        alert(type);
    }
});
```

Here it give you the type for input like radio text email or the tag name for other tags like textarea